# Posting on User's friend's wall with Facebook

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

Is there any way to post something to a user's friend's wall from that user in my facebook app?

Example: A user of my facebook app answers a question about one of his friends. I want a small message to be posted to the wall of that friend saying 'Bob answered a question about you...'

Is that possible? If so, how?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that this is possible, the following code is working:

```
 $result = $facebook->api('/$friendsUserId/feed', 'POST', array(                
            'name'    => 'TEST NAME',
            'caption' => 'Test Caption',
            'description' => 'Test Description',
            'message' => 'this is a test.',
        ));
    print_r($result);
    die;
```

Comment: you can remove the 'from'-node, it's not supported by the fb graph api while posting. I would guess it's just ignored. All supported nodes are listed on this page under the topic Publishing: http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/post/

Comment: It seems that they use the access_token that you provide to identify who the user is. If you have offline_access permission it means the user doesn't have to be logged in to the app for you to be able to make such posts